# How to use annotation for request in Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a APIService class for request URL.

I want to set "/products?page=1" to annotation @GET but I want that I can change parameter and value.

this is my APIService class:

```
public interface APIService {

 @GET("products?{parameter}={value}")
  Call<List<DataModelProducts>> getProducts(@Path("parameter") String  parameter,@Path("value") String value);
}
```

How can I change "parameter" and "value" in my app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it will be sufficient to use `@Query` Annotation like below :

```
@GET("group/{id}/users/list")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @Query("sort") String sort);
```

it will create a request like: `.../users/list?sort=desc`

or if you want to be able to change both sort/desc as for the sample request above you can use `@QueryMap`:

```
@GET("group/{id}/users/list")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

this will create a request like: `.../users/list?key=value`
where the key/value are specified in the `Map<String, String> options`

for more information on different Annotations for Retrofit2, you can visit 
[Retrofit API Declarations](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: I want I can change "sort"

Comment: tank you so much

Comment: happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your page number is passed as a query parameter. To pass query parameter in retrofit, you need to pass it like:

```
public interface APIService {

 @GET("products")
 Call<List<DataModelProducts>> getProducts(@Query("page") String pagerNumber);
}
```

EDIT: to use a query map:

```
public interface APIService {

 @GET("products")  Call<List<DataModelProducts>> getProducts(@QueryMap HashMap queryParams); }
```

Here, whatever you add as the key will replce "page" and value will be added.
for eg if hash map has: 
queryParams.put("something", "value");..

you request will be like:

> url?something=value

Comment: I want I can change "page" to anything

Comment: Queryparam is the way to go then

Comment: how to use it ?

Comment: tank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public interface APIService {
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @GET("/products?page=1")
 Call<List<DataModelProducts>> getProducts(@Field("parameter") String  
 parameter,@Field("value") String value);
}
```